# Unable to build due to API update

Tags: c#, api, activex

I have a problem with making an ActiveX program with C#.

I'm trying to make a **library** that supports all program versions.

For example, assuming there is a A() function in version 1.0.

But in the next version 1.1, A() function is gone.

So I can't build the code in version 1.1 because of the A() function. (IDE Error occurs)

**I want to control all versions with one library.**

Is there any ways to solve this problem?

I used .NET Framwork 4.7.2 and Visual Studio 2019.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do I have to build in version 1.0?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.